# RGBDSLAM Installation Problems

Tags: slam, navigation, linux, g2o, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to install RGBDSLAM on Ubuntu 12 with ROS Fuerte. I know this is not currently supported, but the only error  I have is that g2o seems to depend on eigen which is in the release (as eigen3) and is on my system, but I can't seem to get it to overcome this dependency.

Has anyone had any success with this install. Now trying with Ubuntu 11.10 and ROS electric. Still going on that one!

---

For starters,

```
rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
```

doesn't work. However if you run

```
rosmake rgbdslam
```

I get:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/ben/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120521-184019
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
['rgbdslam']                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> g2o [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf
 No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
 No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs
 No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< g2o [PASS] [ 0.09 seconds ]                            
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesgbdslam: 0.3 sec ]           [ 1 Active 31/32 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package rgbdslam
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests rgbdslam
  [rospack] Error: package/stack g2o depends on non-existent package eigen
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'rgbdslam'.  Look
    above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
    dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:35 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/ben/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120521-184019/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 0.37 seconds ]                       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 32 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/ben/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120521-184019
```

The main error seems to be that g2o can't find eigen

```
 [rospack] Error: package/stack g2o depends on non-existent package eigen
```

My Cmake file for rgbdslam is

```
#########################################################
### CONFIG ##############################################
#########################################################
# 1, if SiftGPU should be used. For additional information
# see README
set(USE_SIFT_GPU        1)
set(ENV{SIFT_GPU_MODE}      2) #CUDA = 1, GLSL = 2
set(ENV{SIFT_GPU_CUDA_PATH} /usr/local/cuda)    
    
set(USE_GICP_BIN        0)
set(USE_GICP_CODE       1)
#########################################################
#########################################################
#########################################################


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")
add_definitions(-DROSCONSOLE_SEVERITY_INFO)
#is used for compiling the libraries 
set(USE_GICP 0)
IF (${USE_GICP_BIN} OR ${USE_GICP_CODE})
    set(USE_GICP 1)
ENDIF (${USE_GICP_BIN} OR ${USE_GICP_CODE})

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
rosbuild_gensrv()
#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library) 
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)


##############################################################################
# Required 3rd party
##############################################################################

#############################
# Qt ########################
#############################
# http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt4_with_cmake
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
SET(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

# This is necessary as all ui files etc will get dumped in the bottom of then binary directory. 
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN)

#get_directory_property(clean ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES)
#SET(clean external/siftgpu/linux/bin/libsiftgpu.so)
#set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${clean}")
    
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
SET(${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
#SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_PROJECT_BEFORE TRUE)



#############################
# SiftGPU ###################
#############################
IF (${USE_SIFT_GPU})
    SET(sift_gpu_build_path ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/siftgpu/linux)

    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} external/siftgpu/src)
    
    MESSAGE("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    MESSAGE("Compiling SiftGPU...")
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(
        COMMAND make siftgpu
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${sift_gpu_build_path}
        RESULT_VARIABLE sift_gpu_return
    )
    MESSAGE("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    
    #on error
    IF (NOT ${sift_gpu_return} EQUAL 0)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "SiftGPU cannot be compiled. Returned: ${sift_gpu_return}")
    ENDIF (NOT ${sift_gpu_return} EQUAL 0)
    
    FILE(COPY external/siftgpu/linux/bin/libsiftgpu.so DESTINATION ../lib/)
    
    add_definitions(-DUSE_SIFT_GPU)
    add_definitions(-DSIFT_GPU_MODE=$ENV{SIFT_GPU_MODE})
ENDIF (${USE_SIFT_GPU})



#############################
# GICP ######################
#############################
IF (${USE_GICP})
    SET(gicp_build_path ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2)
  FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${gicp_build_path}/lib/)
  MESSAGE("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    MESSAGE("Compiling GICP...")
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(
        COMMAND make linux-g++
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${gicp_build_path}
        RESULT_VARIABLE gicp_return
    )
    MESSAGE("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    
    #on error
    IF (NOT ${gicp_return} EQUAL 0)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "GICP cannot be compiled. Returned: ${gicp_return}")
    ENDIF (NOT ${gicp_return} EQUAL 0)
    
    FILE(COPY ${gicp_build_path}/lib/libANN.a DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/)
ENDIF (${USE_GICP})

IF (${USE_GICP_BIN})
    add_definitions(-DUSE_ICP_BIN)
ENDIF (${USE_GICP_BIN})

IF (${USE_GICP_CODE})
    add_definitions(-DUSE_ICP_CODE) 
ENDIF (${USE_GICP_CODE})



#############################
# OpenCV ####################
#############################
find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} external/)

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/local/*.hpp src/qtros.h src/openni_listener.h src/qt_gui.h src/graph_manager.h src/glviewer.h src/ros_service_ui.h)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})  

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################
SET(ADDITIONAL_SOURCES src/gicp-fallback.cpp src/main.cpp src/qtros.cpp  src/openni_listener.cpp src/qt_gui.cpp src/flow.cpp src/node.cpp src/graph_manager.cpp src/glviewer.cpp src/parameter_server.cpp src/ros_service_ui.cpp src/misc.cpp)

IF (${USE_SIFT_GPU})
    SET(ADDITIONAL_SOURCES ${ADDITIONAL_SOURCES} src/sift_gpu_wrapper.cpp)
ENDIF (${USE_SIFT_GPU})

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS ${ADDITIONAL_SOURCES})

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################
rosbuild_add_executable(rgbdslam ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})

#set libs
SET(G2O_LIBS cholmod g2o_core g2o_stuff g2o_types_slam3d g2o_solver_cholmod g2o_solver_pcg g2o_solver_csparse cxsparse g2o_incremental)
SET(LIBS_LINK rgbdslam GL GLU cholmod g2o_cli g2o_core g2o_incremental g2o_interactive g2o_interface g2o_math_groups g2o_parser g2o_solver_cholmod g2o_solver_csparse g2o_solver_dense g2o_solver_pcg g2o_stuff g2o_types_icp g2o_types_sba g2o_types_sim3 g2o_types_slam2d g2o_types_slam3d ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

IF (${USE_SIFT_GPU})
    SET(LIBS_LINK ${LIBS_LINK} siftgpu)
ENDIF (${USE_SIFT_GPU})

IF (${USE_GICP})
    SET(LIBS_LINK ${LIBS_LINK} gicp ANN gsl gslcblas)
ENDIF (${USE_GICP})
#link libraries
target_link_libraries(rgbdslam ${LIBS_LINK})

 
IF (${USE_GICP})
  set(ROS_COMPILE_FLAGS ${ROS_COMPILE_FLAGS} -fpermissive)
  rosbuild_add_library(gicp external/gicp/bfgs_funcs.cpp external/gicp/gicp.cpp external/gicp/optimize.cpp external/gicp/scan.cpp external/gicp/transform.cpp)
ENDIF (${USE_GICP})
```

I've also tried fixing eigen references according to this [link](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/fuerte%282f%29Migration.html#Eigen_can.27t_be_found). But then I could be doing this wrong.

Would appreciate some help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34441/rgbdslam-installation-problems/) by [balunjones](https://answers.ros.org/users/2421/balunjones/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-21**:
Please post exact details of when you get a problem, e.g. errors. I would suspect that you only need to include the proper cmake macros to find eigen.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-21**:
Although it's still no guarantee that there won't be more problems. Have you tried 2.1.1 and 2.1.2 in the g2o package?

**Comment by [balunjones](https://answers.ros.org/users/2421/balunjones/) on 2012-05-21**:
How do you find those packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this.
CMakeLists.txt should have the following lines in this place just above the rosbuild_genmsg().

```
#Eigen required    
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

If Eigen is installed in the system this should work.

Hope it helps, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can fix the eigen dependency by editing the manifest as shown [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/). I followed those directions, but am now stuck with the following error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:103 (MESSAGE):
    SiftGPU cannot be compiled.  Returned: 2
```

Hope you have better luck.

---

Originally posted by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) with karma: 35 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing all this,

sudo apt-get install libglew1.5-dev libdevil-dev libsuitesparse-dev

sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev

Also build g20 package and edit the manifest.xml to solve the eigen package problem.

I hope it should work.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1